# Evaluation on-the-fly in String Interpolated Value in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, string-interpolation

I am trying to use an *ngIf in my Angular 2 app, and have it evaluate whether a string interpolated value is set to a certain parameter. I've tried several syntactical constructions, but so far they all return errors. I've tried, for instance, something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="{{info.status === 'consult'}}">
```

I've also tried:

```
<div *ngIf="[{{info.status === 'consult'}}]">
```

And...

```
<div *ngIf="{{info.status}} === 'consult'">
```

What is the correct way to pass in this string interpolated value and have it evaluated on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are inside an Angular2 directive you do not need to put the interpolation syntax. Do this

```
<div *ngIf="info?.status === 'consult'">
```

Comment: I actually tried that, too. And I get this error:

"Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Comment: I know the string interpolation is working, because the correct value is printed right above there in my view, using this:


<div *ngFor="let info of service.workflow">{{info.status}}</div>

Comment: It seems the info hasnt object hasnt been initialized when the template tries to access the status object. try elvis operator ?

Comment: Using the elvis operator gets rid of the error, but I think the problem still exists in that the parameter isn't set by the time the evaluation needs to happen. So the *ngIf has no effect. I'll have to think that through. Your answer was correct though, so thanks.

Comment: @Muirik so if it the status ever becomes 'consult' it should work, the ngIf is checked everytime change detection runs

Comment: Good point, Eduardo. Must have something to do with the way we're massaging the data then. I will have a look. Thanks again.